# PhP database function

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm not sure how I can query a MYSQL database with PHP by incoming URL value. For example my API receives `?name=Radi` and I want to check if there's user with name "Radi" in my database.

```
// How to define isNameExisting. Can I use PDO or something similar?
if (isNameExisting) {
  echo"OK"
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what to do to edit this question, but this `$–REQUEST['NAME']` is obviously incorrect. It's an underscore and not a hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php's [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) and MySQL's [count()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) for that.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));


$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT
        Count(*) as c
    FROM
        tablename
    WHERE
        name=?
');

$stmt->execute( array($_REQUEST['NAME']) );
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if ( intval($row['c']) > 0 ) {
    echo 'Ok';
}
else {
    echo 'no such record';
}
```